# If it is to hard for one to avoid smoking during fast than What is the expiation of it?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, sawm

Many people not fast only because they cannot stop them self from smoking.what should be done in such a cases, Should they fast and pay a penalty for it?

Comment: Well, that is to be blamed indeed. And no, they do not have to pay penalty, because God Says: “O believers, turn to your Lord in repentance that you might succeed”. So, if a person stopped from smoking, he only have to do is to seek God’s forgiveness and make full intention to never return to that filthy sin again.

Comment: Please don't confound us with a fatwa site.

Comment: If one smokes when he should be fasting scholars may hold two positions either he is breaking his fast willingly/intentionally or due to a need (which I'd consider the weakest position, but Allah knows best) depending on the qualification a ruling might be concluded.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, smoking is not a good thing for your health.
  Medical science tells that it is injurious to health, but on the other hand in the sense of Islamic point of view actually smoking cigarettes are known as narcotics and narcotics are prohibited in Islam and no privileged if you have fast or not simply clear and cut. Islam tells us Narcotics are haraam for Muslim men and women. In Islam, narcotics are against the rules of Eman because Muhammad P.b.u.h very strictly said about any type of narcotics.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided evidences supporting your claims and read [answer].